# Why the post made by Graph API application doesn't display on 'home' news feed?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

My application is working fine, it posts on the users wall, but the post doesn't show on news feed at 'home'. why is this happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I faced this problem too. It seems Facebook 'downgrades' third party app posts. Also users can decide to block posts, posted by third party apps. More info here: http://mashable.com/2011/09/09/facebook-third-party-apps-study/